# Array y el metodo de la burbuja

Tags: array, c

chicos tengo este problema de ARRAY y lo realice con el método de la burbuja en lenguaje C, pero por alguna extra razón en la posición 0 del array 3(C) me cambia el valor por 0, sacando el ultimo valor del arreglo, y lo único que hago es pedir al final que lo arregle de mayor a menor de verdad no logro entender, espero sepan ayudarme, gracia!!!

Aca esta mi codigo:

printf("Que lea 5 números por teclado, los copie a otro array multiplicados por 2 y los muestre todos ordenados usando un tercer array.\n\n");

```c
int a[5], b[5], c[10], aux = 0;

// Genero los valores para la tabla A

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    printf("Ingrese el %d valor:  ", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}

// Multiplico los valores de la tabla A para crear la B

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    b[i] = a[i] * 2;
}
printf("\n\n");

// Paso valores a tabla C

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    c[i] = a[i];
    printf("%d\n", c[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    c[5 + i] = b[i];
    printf("%d\n", c[i]);
}

for (int a = 0; a < 10; ++a) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 10; ++b) {
        if (c[b] > c[b + 1]) {
            aux = c[b];
            c[b] = c[b + 1];
            c[b + 1] = aux;
        }
    }
}

printf("\n\n");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    printf("%d : %d\n", i, c[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: trata de hacer un print de los valores de c cada vez que se le asigne uno nuevo y asi ves donde se rompe la logica

Comment: Hola, si , hice que imprimiera el array antes de que se me ordene para ver si algun valor me lo cambia o no lo toma y todo esta bien, todo pasa cuando pasa al ordenarlos por el metodo de la burbuja, ahi es que sucede todo y he practicado varias cosas y nada....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error esta justo en el ***segundo for del método burbuja***, debería ser de esta manera

```
for (int b = 0; b < 10 - 1; ++b)
```

Y eso no ocurre, por eso te arroja 0.

Recuerda que nuestro algoritmo es el siguiente.

algoritmo Burbuja

```
inicio
// Ordenaciones 
desde i ← 1 hasta n-1 hacer
    // Comparaciones
    desde j ← 1 hasta n-i hacer
        si elemento[j] > elemento[j+1] entonces
            // Intercambiar los elementos
            aux ← V[j]
            V[j] ← V[j+1]
            V[j+1] ← aux
        fin_si
    fin_desde
fin_desde
fin
```

Comment: De verdad muchas gracias no lo habia visto, es logico, pero no lo veia, mil gracias